# Begin ordered list from 0 in Markdown

Tags: html-lists, markdown

I'm new to **Markdown**. I was writing something like:

```
# Table of Contents  
0. Item 0  
1. Item 1  
2. Item 2
```

But that generates a list that starts with 1, effectively rendering something like:

```
# Table of Contents
1. Item 0
2. Item 1
3. Item 2
```

I want to start the list from zero. Is there an easy way to do that?

If not, I could simply rename all of my indices, but this is annoying when there are several items. Beginning a list from zero seems so natural to me, it's like beginning the index of an array from zero.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Simply: **NO**

Longer: **YES, BUT**

When you create ordered list in Markdown it is parsed to HTML ordered list, i.e.:

```
# Table of Contents

0. Item 0  
1. Item 1  
2. Item 2
```

Will create:

```
<h1>Table of Contents</h1>
<ol>
  <li>Item 0</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

So as you can see, there is no data about starting number. If you want to start at certain number, unfortunately, you have to use pure HTML and write:

```
<ol start="0">
  <li>Item 0</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use HTML **start** tag:

```
<ol start="0">
  <li> item 1</li>
  <li> item 2</li>
  <li> item 3</li>
</ol>
```

It's currently supported in all browsers: Internet Explorer 5.5+, Firefox 1+, Safari 1.3+, Opera 9.2+, Chrome 2+

Optionally you can use **type** tab for more sophisticated enumerating:

- `type="1"` - decimal (default style)
- `type="a"` - lower-alpha
- `type="A"` - upper-alpha
- `type="i"` - lower-roman
- `type="I"` - upper-roman

Answer (score 4):

Via html: use `<ol start="0">`

Via CSS:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: num -1; // reset counter to -1 (any var name is possible)
}
ol li {
    list-style-type: none; // remove default numbers
}
ol li:before {
    counter-increment: num; // increment counter
    content: counter(num) ". "; 
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gepvkx6p/)

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Depends on the implementation.

The current version of [CommonMark](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.27/#list-items) requires the `start` attribute. Some implementations already support this, e.g. pandoc and markdown-it. For more details see [babelmark](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=0.+Item+0++%0A1.+Item+1++%0A2.+Item+2).