# Is there a way to begin GFM ordered lists at 0?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

Is it possible to have an ordered list in Github Flavored Markdown that begins with '0'?

Just typing `0.` at the beginning is getting rendered as '1.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considered [GitHub Flavored Markdown (GFM)](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/) is [markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/markdown-basics/) [plus a few features](http://codemirror.net/mode/gfm/), the answer would be the same as for "[Begin ordered list from 0 in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15078393/6309)":

> If you want to start at certain number, unfortunately, you have to use pure HTML and write:

```
<ol start="0">
  <li>Item 0</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you! Did not realize we could use normal HTML like that.